# File paths, root up and down

Tags: javascript, html, css

.I'm confused which way is up,  in the file paths. It's taken me months and I still and struggling with it. 
These files are separated by one.
Which is the root? (Path) 
If the file is destination is above the file, or below the file how is the URL (../
)

Comment: Could you give an example perhaps of a part of code that's referring to up and down filepaths so that we can better instruct you regarding your question?

Comment: . means the current directory, .. means go up one directory

Answer (score 0):

The root is referred to as simply "/" for a website, e.g.

`<img src="/test.jpg" />` will pull the test.jpg from your website's root folder.

This can also be done with "../", which is one step above the current location, and can not go higher up than the root folder, e.g.

`<img src="../../../../test.jpg" />` will pull the same image as the last example, assuming you aren't more 4 folders down from the root when you request it.

Just for clarification, omitting the "/" altogether is a relative path from where the request is made, e.g.

If the url is `example.com/subfolder` and the request is made for `<img src="test.jpg" />`, the image will be pulled from `example.com/subfolder/test.jpg`

[Here is an article with more information on Absolute/Relative Paths](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)